# 2 + 2 = Fish. Who am I?

Tags: lateral-thinking

This is a simple problem that my friend asked me:

> 2 + 2 = Fish
> 3 + 3 = Eight
> 7 + 7 = ?

Can you figure out what is represented by the question mark?

Comment: A slightly flatter fish?

Comment: @Will Or a larger fish without a head.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

My comment was mostly tongue-in-cheek, but here's why I said it (excuse my bad MS Paint skills)

> [image]

The first two are clear, but I've no idea what the third would be

I suppose, if I don't go quite as far, I get

> [image]
>  Upside-down triangle

Comment: you are almost there..

Comment: yes.. you are correct. :) :)

Comment: Actually, from your first picture I would have called the solution "tie" or "scarf"....

Comment: It looks like a ribbon to me.

Comment: Person standing with their legs crossed.